# Salesforce bulk api using the python simplesalesforce package

Tags: python, python-3.x, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I am using the simple-salesforce python package with python 3. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce), I should be able to bulk update records using this syntax:

```
data = [{'Id': '0000000000AAAAA', 'Email': 'examplenew@example.com'}, {'Id':'0000000000BBBBB', 'Email': 'testnew@test.com'}]

sf.bulk.Contact.update(data)
```

However the instance of simple-salesforce that I implemented does not recognize

```
sf.bulk.Custom_Object__c
```

When I try to execute:

```
sf.bulk.Custom_Object__c.update(data)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-126-b287358940fc> in <module>()
----> 1 sf.bulk.Custom__bject__c.update(data)

AttributeError: 'SFType' object has no attribute 'Custom_Object__c'
```

Has anyone else worked with the simple-salesforce python package and run into this issue before?

Comment: Same issue with Python 2.7.13

Comment: Those libraries are changing the attribute names like method and all in new versions and no proper instructions about that. You can verify that attribute in the sample code in their document. I've gone through similar issue. Salesforce-bulk library changed thier attribute post_bulk_batch in 1.1.0 to post_batch in 2.1.0 version

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Salesforce()` function to login instead of `SFType()`. Here an example:

## 1. Login

```
import pandas as pd
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

sf = Salesforce(username='my_username', password='my_password', security_token = 'my_token', domain = 'login')
```

## 2. Data

In case you are using `pandas` to manage your data, you will need to convert your `df` to a **list of dictionaries** using `df.to_dict('records')` method  before the update.

```
fake_df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ['rowID1', 'rowID2'], 'CustomField__c':[1,2]})
fake_dict = fake_df.to_dict('records')
```

## 3. Update

Although you could use `sf.bulk.MyCustomObject__c` to set the name of the SFDC object to be updated, I prefer `sf.bulk.__getattr__(objectName)` so you can reuse the code in a function and easily switch objects.

```
objectName = 'MyCustomObject__c'
results = sf.bulk.__getattr__(objectName).update(fake_dict, batch_size = 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `sf.bulk.Custom_Object__c.update(data)` regularly and have never encountered this issue. I would suggest trying out the following troubleshooting methods:

- In Salesforce, go to the object in the setup menu and make sure you are using the correct **API Name**. Sometimes custom objects' **labels** differ from their API Names (i.e. if the object label was changed after creation)
- Confirm that your simple-salesforce initialization code (`sf = Salesforce(password=userPassword, username=userName, organizationId=orgId)`) is bringing you into the correct org (that your `orgId` is correct)
- As a last ditch effort, you could try reinstalling simple-salesforce. I suggest this as normally errors I encounter with this type of command results in a `SalesforceMalformedRequest` error rather than a `Attribution` error, and it is possible you are using an out-of-date version of Simple-Salesforce